# Why bookmarks listing is empty after I added new bookmark?

Tags: phpstorm

Can anybody explain why on PhpStorm 2019.3.4 after I create bookmarks and can check them by clicking
they are in bookmarks listing by SHIFT+F11 key. But If I click  SHIFT+F11 key after some period
of time(maybe in 30 minutes or 1 hours ) I see that bookmarks listing is empty?

I suppose that all bookmarks are saved in /.idea/workspace.xml file.
I check content this file and did not see any bookmarks content...
Even after I created some new bookmark. Are there some bookmarks options for (time) saving etc...

Thanks!

Comment: I removed  /.idea/ directory, supposing that  recreating /.idea/workspace.xml  file will fix this problem, but thst did not happen... Also I did not any relative  bookmarks options  under Settings menu.

Comment: Is your project, including the `/.idea` folder, under a file-sync software monitoring? E.g. OneDrive, Google Drive, DropBox? If it is - try disabling their services for a while & check if that helps.

Comment: That is my home laptop with Kubuntu 18 and I have no any file-sync software monitoring the project directory.(or some other directory)

Comment: Are you working on a locally stored project? No network shares, symlinks, etc?

Comment: No network shares, but actually on system installed I used command : "ln  -s   /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot  /_wwwroot", so "_wwwroot" - is root of all my projects. Can it be the issue?

Comment: I checked .idea/workspace.xml one more time and see no "/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot" "/_wwwroot" path, but only "$PROJECT_DIR$/"

Comment: The `ln -s` mount shouldn't be a problem then. Are you using VCS like git? If you do: do you have your /.idea/workspace.xml committed by any chance?

Comment: Yes, I use git and  /.idea/ directory is under git(not comited actually). Can this be reason of the error? Have I to add  /.idea/ into ignore file ?

Comment: Yes, this can happen when you e.g. switch to another branch: your bookmark records could get erased from workspace.xml file this way. Here's a gitignore file example that should help you with this: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/JetBrains.gitignore

Comment: Thanks! I hope that will help

Comment: I added /.idea/ into ignore file, but looks like it did not help. 
But I notecied that as I use option “Project Opening ” with selected value 
“Open Project in new window” it seems to me
that Bookmarks list is cleared when I open new project, so I have 2 (sometimes more) instances of PhpStorm.
Can it be the issue? As I expected that Bookmarks list is saved in /.idea/workspace.xml file
inside of any project. I do not know where Bookmarks list is saved really...

Comment: Bookmarks are stored in temporary workspace files located in your [config folder](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2019.3/tuning-the-ide.html#config-directory)/workspace/, at least in up-to-date IDE versions. Unfortunately I don't remember how this worked in version 2019.3. You can check your workspace.xml files for `<component name="BookmarkManager">` entries to control if bookmarks are saved or not.

Comment: In my project/.idea/workspace.xml there are no any BookmarkManager group, but 
I found several such groups in 
files like ~/.PhpStorm2019.3/config/workspace/1qebwc5931sfQbTL2OAJ0RNKxiD.xml
looks like 1 file for any project I work last time.
And looks like I have this error happen when I open other project in other instance of PhpStorm...

Comment: Out of suggestions here, sorry. I'd suggest attaching your IDE logs + affected project's `/.idea` folder + contents of `~/.PhpStorm2019.3/config/workspace/` to a bug report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue for a proper investigation